# how to run node.js client side code with browserify

Tags: node.js

I am using `node.js` at client side with browserify as per reference documents and i am also creating a bundle js with http and browserify-fs js and i am getting both objects on my local project, but i am using fs function for any operation like read file, create directory, appendfile etc,  it's showing me the same problem .

```
Error {errno: 34, code: "ENOENT", path: "/home/nikunjk/tmp", stack: (...), message: "ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/nikunjk/tmp'"}
```

Comment: you will not be able to perform file operations on the client (in the browser)

Comment: But here any solution for that because i am using d3 js but it will create a problem with huge amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from your second comment (and for those that would come looking for a feasible solution to perform file operations):

Use atom/electron to achieve this. You can easily access file system using fs node module and the electron app uses chromium V8 underneath.

Here is a link :
http://electron.atom.io/

I have used it for some project and it works.

**One caution: Dont mix node buffer and html5 apis to read or send files. Use node fs, request and buffers.**